# Typeorm query selection and foreign key

Tags: typeorm

I have 2 entities as follow:

`@Entity()

export default class Employee extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()

id: number;

//other columns go here:

}

@Entity()

export default class Service extends BaseEntity {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()

id: number;

@ManyToOne(() => Employee, Employee => Employee.id)

employee: Employee;

}`

When performing the following query, I’m getting the services along with extra columns in the Employee.  Is it possible to just get just the service with just employeeId.  I just want to get everything in the Service + EmployeeId.  When looking at the Service table, I’m seeing the “employeeId” foreign key, but I can’t include it in the Select.

`Service.createQueryBuilder('service')

.where('service.employee = :employee', { employee })

.leftJoinAndSelect('service.employee', 'employee');`

I tried to use SELECT()

Answer (score 0):

So I end up doing this:

```
@Entity()

export default class Service extends BaseEntity {

       @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

        @ManyToOne(() => Employee)
        @JoinColumn()
        employee: Employee;

        @RelationId((service: Service) => service.employee)
        employeeId: number;

}
```

When performing query, I'm getting back the employeeId and not the relation entity.